# Continue to next tests IF assertEquals fails

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new in Java / Selenium and I am trying to automate some tests. 
So what I am trying to do is to MOVE to the next lines of code IF this test fails and print a message IF this test pass.
Now, I am forcing this test to fail in order to move to the next operations. 
Here is a piece of my code:

```
public class SelfReportingTest {
private WebDriver driver;

@Before
 public void SetUp() {
         driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 }

@Test
public void TestLoginFunctionality() 

String validUsername = "testUsername";
String validPassword = "testPassword";
String validUrl = "https://testsite.com/users/profile/show" // URL when user is successfully logged

driver.get("http://testsite.com");
WebElement loginLink =driver.findElement(By.id("loginLink"));
    loginLink.click();

WebElement usernameField = driver.findElement(By.id("LoginUserName"));

WebElement passwordField = driver.findElement(By.id("LoginPassword"));
usernameField.sendKeys(validUsername);
passwordField.sendKeys(validPassword);

WebElement loginButton =driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/form/div/div[2]/input"));
loginButton.click();

if(validUrl != driver.getCurrentUrl()) {
        driver.get("http://test.jira.com");
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println("login successfull");
```

I am struggling at the IF condition - always taking the first condition, no matter if username/password are correct/incorrect.
It's not mandatory to compare URLs, I can do that with some WebElements, but I am not sure is that the right way?
I tried assertEquals but it just fails when actual and expected are not equal, so it does not fit to my needs.
Can you guys suggest something, which will work in this case?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `assert.True(driver.getTitle()=="page name");` or find an element and check `IsDisplayed`.

Ex: `driver.findElement(By.Id("")).isDisplayed;`

Answer (score 0):

```
You care checking the current URL with your assigned URL as "validURl" which is : 

String validUrl = "https://testsite.com/users/profile/show"

Some time the Current URL string changed after login so if you do an exact match it may return you FALSE. But you can check .contains() which will compare 2 string and check the existence of validUrl in driver.getCurrentUrl().

Your code ( But Note its not the BEST way, you can use .equals or .contains)

    if(!driver.getCurrentUrl().equals(validUrl)) {
            driver.get("http://test.jira.com");
        }
        else { 
            System.out.println("login successfull");


The better way to check the Page Title as it may move from Login to Home  or you can verify any existence of the web element in the page ( Note add a try catch block during finding webElement to print the else part as if the exception will come in if the else will not get get executed and you will not see the sysout statement you have added.


try(){
 if(driver.fineElement(By.<Element in your home Page after login>)){
  {
   Print You are Logged in
   }
}
catch(exception elementNotfound){
Print You are not logged in as Exception comes on Finding the Element
}


There are better way to handle the code using driverListener but you can now start with this.

So the Page title verification is a good idea for you to check you are in Login Page of Home Page
```